# ソースを取得せずにgit logだけしたい

Tags: git

あるリポジトリのgit logだけが見たい場合

```
git clone リポジトリ
git log
```

とソース自体は欲しくないのですがcloneをしています。

ソース量が多いリポジトリですとlogを見たいだけなのにローカルの容量を開けなければならなかったり、取得に時間がかかってしまうので、
logだけ見る方法はありませんでしょうか。

Comment: コミットメッセージだけ見ることができれば充分ですか？　それとも、`git diff` などができる必要がありますか？

Comment: 可能ならばgit diffやgit blameも使用したいですが、最低限コミットメッセージを見れれば良いと考えています。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git clone` の [`--bare` オプション](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#git-clone---bare) を使えば `.git` フォルダだけを clone し、コード部分は除くことができます。ただしこの部分にはコードの差分情報なども含まれているため、レポジトリによってはダウンロード量があまり変わらないこともあります。（必要に応じて [`--depth` オプション](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#git-clone---depthltdepthgt)や [`--single-branch` オプション](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#git-clone---no-single-branch)が有用かもしれません。）

GitHub や BitBucket 上のレポジトリであれば、ウェブサイトからログを見るのが早そうです。コミットメッセージ、簡単なdiff、blame の確認ならブラウザ上で行えます。どうしても CLI 上が良いなら、API 経由でもらってくることは可能です。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。`ただしこの部分にはコードの差分情報なども含まれているため、レポジトリによってはダウンロード量があまり変わらないこともあります。`がやはり気になってしまうのですが。純粋にログだけを見るという所作は不可能で、ご教示頂いた所までが限界ということですよね。

Comment: `git diff` や `git blame` をするためには差分情報が必要なはずなので、しょうがないと思います。コミットメッセージだけを貰う git コマンドは、あるのかもしれませんが私は存じあげないですね……。